# Doxygen integration with (unmanaged) Visual C++ 2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, doxygen, visual-c++-2005

We are slowly moving towards better-standardized commenting in a large C++ project, introducing Doxygen. I personally find it a pain typing in comments, especially since Java IDEs are so good at automating this.

So I wondered what tools there might be? A search turned up **[DoxyComment](http://doxycomment.sourceforge.net/vs2005_addin.html)** which looks quite nice, is this the best/standard tool or are there others worth a look too?

Answer (score 1):

Atomineer is a tool that I and a few others have been using for documenting unmanaged C++ code with Doxygen markup. It's not free, but it is cheap, and may be worth a try:
http://www.atomineerutils.com/products.php

Answer (score 1):

If typing the meta-comments which are instructions to doxygen is a significant part of your comment-writing effort, you're doing it wrong.

Comment should not include things which can be automatically determined by a tool, any programmer will determine just as much (or more) information from e.g. parameter names than any tool.

Another way to look at this is that doxygen already does an excellent job of presenting what can be automatically determined.  You don't need to write: "B::B constructs a B object", since doxygen is going to sort it into the constructors section of the documentation automatically.

Focus on what's non-obvious, and take time to think about what you're writing.

Normally many functions and variables will have no need for an individual comment, since either the name is descriptive enough, or they are better explained in a class-level comment describing how multiple members interact.